# @ExceptionHandler annotated method in ControllerAdvice class is not invoked when exceptions are thrown

Tags: java, spring, exception, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

I have a problem, as the title suggests my method annotated with @ExceptionHandler is not invoked when exceptions are thrown. I've tried using as an argument of @ExceptionHandler(...) annotation both specific exceptions as well as their superclasses. I've tried debugging it and put a breakpoint inside handleExceptions() method annotated with @ExceptionHandler but it didn't go inside. I thought that maybe spring context does not see my GlobalExceptionHandler class as a spring bean and checked the logs in debug mode and GlobalExceptionHandler class is registered as a spring bean: `2024-03-06 11:54:29.123 DEBUG 10196 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'globalExceptionHandler'`. I don't have the faintest idea what the problem is, thanks in advance:

Project tree:

[image]

Main class:

```
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"pl.esp", "pl.o4b"})
public class DocumentServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DocumentServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

ControllerAdvice class

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
//tried annotating it with @Component even though @RestController has this annotation within itself, but it did'nt work
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(PublishDocumentException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleExceptions(final PublishDocumentException ex) {
        log.info("Exception thrown {}", ex.getClass().getName());
        final ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
        errorResponse.setDescription(String.valueOf(ex.getCause()));
        errorResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.valueOf(ex.code()));
        errorResponse.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, errorResponse.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

ErrorResponse Class

```
@Getter
@Setter
//tried annotating it with @Component too
public class ErrorResponse {
    private String description;
    private HttpStatus statusCode;
    private String message;
    private String reference;
}
```

method throwing exception

```
@ApplicationService
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Slf4j
public class DocumentServiceImpl{
public PublishDocumentResponse publishDocument(final String sessionId) {
  //...logic//
            throw new PublishDocumentException(FAILED_TO_GENERATE_PDF_DOCUMENT);
    }
}
```

PublishException class

```
public class PublishDocumentException extends HttpRuntimeException {
    public PublishDocumentException(final String body) {
        super(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, body);
    }
}
```

HttpRunTimeException class

```
public class HttpRuntimeException extends GeneralRuntimeException implements MessageException<Integer, String, String> {
    public HttpRuntimeException(int httpStatus, String body) {
        super(httpStatus, body);
    }

    public HttpRuntimeException(int httpStatus, String body, Object... params) {
        super(httpStatus, body, params);
    }
}
```

Controller method:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Slf4j
public class DocumentController {

private final DocumentService documentServiceImpl;


    @GetMapping(value = "/documents/declarations/generate",
            produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<PublishDocumentResponse> generateDocument(@RequestParam final String sessionId) {
        var response = documentServiceImpl.generateDocument(sessionId);
        log.info("Document generated  successfully! Responding status: {}!", HttpStatus.OK);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: in which package is located `GlobalExceptionHandler`, it must be in a subpackage where the @SpringBootAppication is, or you have to make a  `@ComponentScan`  to find it

Comment: @Pp88 it is in a subpackage, I even tried to put it in the same package but it didn't work

Comment: [here](https://github.com/paolopiccinini/car-service-api) there is a working example

Comment: @Pp88 everything in my code is as far as I can tell exactly the same as in your example and yet it still does not work

Comment: Can u upload a minimal example on github. I’ll try to take a look

Comment: @Pp88 Hey. Sorry for answering sa late. Here's a link to my repo with an example. It's a different example but with the same problem: https://github.com/Krzysiek-lab/handler